# Blank screen comes up or closes when I run my app (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, firebase

when I run my project, first "splash_screen(Main Activity)" then "login_page" and other screens should be opened. But when I run it with the android studio emulator avd, the "splash screen" opens and the application closes, when I run it with bluestack 5, the "splash screen" opens and then a blank page opens. I don't have a blank screen in my project and I couldn't figure out what could be the problem and I need serious help in this regard.
thank you in advance everyone

login_page repo

```
public class login_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView createnewAccount, forgotPassword;
    EditText inputEmail,inputPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
        createnewAccount=findViewById(R.id.createNewAccount5);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        inputEmail=findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        inputPassword=findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
        btnLogin=findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        forgotPassword=findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();


        createnewAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(login_page.this, register_page.class));
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                perforLogin();
            }
        });
        forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText resetMail = new EditText((v.getContext()));
                AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Şifre Yenileme");
                passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Şifre Yenileme Linki için Kayıtlı Email Adresinizi Girin...");
                passwordResetDialog.setView(resetMail);

                passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Evet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        String mail = resetMail.getText().toString();
                        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(mail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                Toast.makeText(login_page.this, "Yenileme Linki Email Adresinize Gönderildi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(login_page.this, "Hata ! Yenileme Linki Email Adresinize Gönderilemedi."+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
                passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("Hayır", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.create().show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void perforLogin() {
        String email=inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String password=inputPassword.getText().toString();

        if(!email.matches(emailPattern))
        {
            inputEmail.setError("Geçerli Email Girin");
        }
        else if(password.isEmpty() || password.length()<6)
        {
            inputPassword.setError("Geçerli Paraloyı Girin");
        }
        else
        {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Giriş Yapılıyor... ");
            progressDialog.setTitle("Giriş");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.show();

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        sendUserToNextActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(login_page.this, "Giriş Başarılı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(login_page.this, ""+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void sendUserToNextActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(login_page.this,home_page.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

splash screen (MainActivity) repo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler handler;
    private TextView txt_app_name;
    private Animation textViewAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_app_name = findViewById(R.id.text_app_name);
        textViewAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.textview_animation);

        handler = new Handler();


        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login_page.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 11800);

        txt_app_name.setAnimation(textViewAnimation);
    }
}
```

logcat of error

```
    2021-12-21 16:26:53.396 1776-25638/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
    2021-12-21 16:26:53.411 1776-25638/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{d3f4f08 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
    2021-12-21 16:26:59.079 1776-25638/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
    2021-12-21 16:26:59.096 1776-25638/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{646a86f u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
    2021-12-21 16:27:01.492 1776-3798/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
    2021-12-21 16:27:01.513 1776-3798/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{bb242b2 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
    2021-12-21 16:27:02.754 1776-2170/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
    2021-12-21 16:27:02.778 1776-2170/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{4def2d u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
    2021-12-21 16:27:15.567 1776-1787/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
    2021-12-21 16:27:15.583 1776-1787/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{f4442a4 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
    2021-12-21 16:27:20.684 1776-2170/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
    2021-12-21 16:27:20.718 1776-2170/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{83db9c3 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
    2021-12-21 16:27:26.633 1776-1787/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
    2021-12-21 16:27:26.661 1776-1787/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{b785b96 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord.pid' on a null object reference
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.fillInProcMemInfo(ActivityManagerService.java:14248)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getMyMemoryState(ActivityManagerService.java:14355)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1719)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2846)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
2021-12-21 16:31:31.533 1776-3798/system_process E/ActivityManager: Activity Manager Crash
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord.pid' on a null object reference
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.fillInProcMemInfo(ActivityManagerService.java:14248)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getMyMemoryState(ActivityManagerService.java:14355)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1719)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2846)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
2021-12-21 16:31:41.496 1776-1788/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
2021-12-21 16:31:41.515 1776-1788/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{3c834b0 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
2021-12-21 16:31:49.417 1776-2170/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
2021-12-21 16:31:49.456 1776-2170/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{434433f u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
2021-12-21 16:31:55.026 1776-25638/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
2021-12-21 16:31:55.059 1776-25638/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{1d673d3 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
2021-12-21 16:31:59.666 1776-2170/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
2021-12-21 16:31:59.723 1776-2170/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{e136772 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
2021-12-21 16:32:04.234 1776-1984/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
2021-12-21 16:32:04.252 1776-1984/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{26d1eed u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
2021-12-21 16:32:06.749 1776-2167/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1504)
2021-12-21 16:32:06.785 1776-2167/system_process E/ActivityManager: Attempting to schedule restart of ServiceRecord{dda9e88 u0 lara.alev.reklamizleme/com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService} when found in map: null
2021-12-21 16:32:09.102 1776-1787/system_process E/ActivityManager: Activity Manager Crash
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord.pid' on a null object reference
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.fillInProcMemInfo(ActivityManagerService.java:14248)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getMyMemoryState(ActivityManagerService.java:14355)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1719)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2846)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Comment: kindly share logcat of error

Comment: and you dont have to check conditions for email pattern and password, firebase will take care of it

Comment: thank you and I added the logcat of errors

Comment: I think this article, [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) might help.

Comment: I still haven't been able to solve this problem.